# Get specific attribute of object from a variable in Swiftui

Tags: arrays, swift, object, foreach, swiftui

I want to create a list in my RankingView, to show ranks of my players.
Type of ranking can be choose in a picker. Players can show rank by Highscore or by numbers of attempts

```
let rankChoice = ["highScore","attempt"]
@State var listRank : [Player] = []
@State var selectedIndex = 0 // gives selected index from Picker
```

Player is define like :

```
Struct Player: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID
    let playerName : String
    let highscore : Int
    let attempt : Int
}
```

And finally I want to show a List, with player.playerName and (player.highscore OR player.attempt) depending of user choice in my picker.

```
List{
    ForEach(0 ..< listRank.count, id: \.self) { index in
        HStack{
            Text("\(listRank[index].playerName)")
            Spacer()
            Text(String(listRank[index].rankChoice[selectedIndex]))
        }
    }
}
```

So I'm trying to get : **listRank[index].rankChoice[selectedIndex]**

Error : But Player as no member rankChoice.

How should I get specific attribute from a variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift, you can't access properties by Strings.

Here is one possible solution:

```
List {
    ForEach(0 ..< listRank.count, id: \.self) { index in
        HStack {
            Text("\(listRank[index].playerName)")
            Spacer()
            if selectedIndex == 0 {
                Text(String(listRank[index].highScore))
            } else {
                Text(String(listRank[index].attempt))
            }
        }
    }
```

---

**Use KeyPaths**

If all of your properties that you want to display have the same type (for example, `Int`), then KeyPaths are a good solution.

```
let rankChoice = [\Player.highscore, \Player.attempt]
```

and then:

```
Text(String(listRank[index][keyPath: rankChoice[selectedIndex]]))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I reduce my code for the question, but Player has multiple attributes... ( I removed for the question) to make it easier to understand. Your answer works but I was thinking about something shorter...

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer ! I have different type in my rank choice but that was Int and Int32, so everything is going to be Int32

Comment: If all of your properties didn't have the same type, you could use computed variables in the struct to expose the same type.  For instance, you could have a `String` version of every property by adding a computed property such as `var highscoreStr: String { String(highscore) }`.  Then all of the key paths could reference the string versions of the properties.